# Merging/unmerging cells does not work with IE or Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, merge, cells

Here is the issue I'm currently having.

I have an HTML table with five columns and 50 rows. some of the cells in the columns have repeated text that I would like to have the option to merge or unmerge. Here is my merge function

```
function mergeGridCells()
{
    var dimension_col = null;

    dimension_col = 1;

    // first_instance holds the first instance of identical td
    var first_instance = null;
    var rowspan=1;
    var columnCount = $("#mainTable tr:first th").length;

    for (dimension_col = 1; dimension_col <= columnCount; dimension_col++) {
        var first_instance = null;
        var rowspan = 1;
        $("#mainTable").find('tr:visible').each(function() {
            var dimension_td = $(this).find('td:nth-child(' + dimension_col + '):visible');
            if (first_instance == null) {
                // must be the first row
                first_instance = dimension_td;
            } else if (dimension_td.text() == first_instance.text()) {
                // the current td is identical to the previous
                // remove the current td
                dimension_td.hide();
                ++rowspan;
                // increment the rowspan attribute of the first instance
                first_instance.attr('rowspan', rowspan);
                first_instance.css('vertical-align', 'middle');
                first_instance.css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
            } else {
                // this cell is different from the last
                first_instance = dimension_td;
                rowspan=1;
            }
        });
    }

    $('#mainTable tr > td:nth-child(1)').css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
    $temp1 = $('#mainTable td:nth-child(1):not([rowspan]):visible');
    $temp1.css('background-color',$temp1.next().css('background-color'));

    $('#mainTable').trigger('update',[false]);
}
```

This function works great in all browsers (Chrome, IE/Edge, Firefox, and Opera). The problem is when I try to unmerge the cells once they have been merged. Here is the function I'm currently using to unmerge the cells.

```
function unmergeCells() {
        $temp = $("#mainTable td[rowspan]");

        $temp.each(function() {
            $(this).attr("rowspan", "0");   
        });

        $("#mainTable td:hidden").show();

        $("#mainTable td").css("background-color","");
        $("#mainTable tr:not(:has(th))").css("background-color","#FFFFFF");
        $("#mainTable tr:not(:has(th)):odd").css("background-color","#D4D4D4");
}
```

This function works well with Chrome and Opera but not in Firefox/Edge. Is there a way I can improve the code to make it work in Firefox/Edge?

Comment: "Does not work" is not a technical term. Explain what it's not doing.

Comment: I would suggest that setting `rowspan="0"` is the issue - try removing the `rowspan` attribute instead

Comment: Sorry Rob. In Firefox/IE when trying to unmerge (split) it does not render well, it messes up the columns.

Comment: Jaromanda X. You got it right. the issue was with the rowspan="0". I changed it to rowspan="1" and it works. Just wondering, If I want to remove the rowspan attribute how can I do it?

Comment: Nevermind. I found the .removeAttr() method. Thanks for the help!